# htmlspecialchars handling hebrew words

Tags: php, xss

I want to use htmlspecialchars to english and hebrew words, but when I save a hebrew word, it save it as the code of the word (e.g. `&#1513;&#1500;&#1493;&#1501;` for "שלום"). Code:

```
 $txt=htmlspecialchars($txt, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

I tried to use htmlentities, but same result.

I thought maybe to make htmlspecialchars  by hand, i.e. change `>` to `'&gt;'` and `""` to `&#039;` etc .

Does it safe to do it?

And how can I do it?(replace special chars to their code) I didn't find explanation how to make it

Edit- I solved it:
need to add this code

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

I declared the html header as utf8, but I didn't declare also the php as utf8.

Comment: You're supplying UTF-8? Is the character set default for PHP also UTF-8?

Comment: *"when I **save** a hebrew word, it **save** it as the code of the word"* ~ What do you mean by "save"?

Comment: I save the result in mysql (i guess i should have exlain it )